# Curl Command does not convert to postman request- developer DocusignAPI

Tags: docusignapi

I was trying to convert the curl command list below into a postman request but postman keeps on throwing the error that the format is not recognized (after clicking on import and pasting raw text from url below). Any ideas how to fix this?

URL:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email

Comment: postman usually just deals with URLs and JSON. Not sure what you did exactly, but the URL below has code and scripts, not just JSON. Can you provide more details and the exact code you copied over?

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit - for example i copied this which is listed as step 2 in the page above `curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${accessToken}" \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data-binary @${request_data} \
     --request POST ${basePath}/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes \
     --output ${response}`

Comment: and you replaced anything with $(variable) with values? cause that's CURL, Postman doesn't know these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just use the repo as for curl and hence this is resolved.